# Would it be alright to run Antivirus docker container to scan host system?

Tags: docker, anti-virus

We are using a CSP's customized linux (Alibaba Cloud Linux 3, ACL3), and every antivirus software we asked stated that they do not support ACL3.

And we don't want to migrate all servers to another OS because of linux antivirus compatibility.

So I'm wondering if it's okay to install dockerized antivirus client and make it scan the host system if it is possible.

But I haven't done something like this before and it seems unnatural. What is the right approach from here?